# which specific field to study to know more about genes and genomes

Tags: evolution, gene, genomes

I recently got interested in specific subjects : 
1.Evolution
2. DNA, genomes etc and its structure
3. Abiogenesis

I am a software engineer with good fundamental understanding in math & physics and I was thinking to read some biology to get knowledge on it in my free time.

An associate free course or a book which can build my broader understanding in fields of biology would definitely help.

Regards

Comment: People who downvoted are seriously useless if they do not consider leaving a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for fields with names like "genomics" "genome evolution", "population genetics", "molecular evolution", and possibly "computational biology"/"bioinformatics".

Each of these is a huge field with a large literature. I'll try to recommend some resources but they're not exhaustive.

For a simple mathematical introduction to population genetics and microevolution, I like Joe Felsenstein's book ([free online](http://evolution.gs.washington.edu/pgbook/pgbook.pdf)).

Joe furthermore has a lot of [slides up along with audio tracks](http://evolution.gs.washington.edu/courses.html) for courses he's taught covering several of these areas. He is coming at it from the perspective of a mathematically-sophisticated computational biologist with an interest in designing software for phylogenetic inference, so it might be a point of view that works for you. I'm sure that there are lots of other similar resources but I'll admit that I'm personally fond of Joe's style.

It does look like there are [online courses for genomics intros](https://online-learning.harvard.edu/course/introduction-genomics), I don't know how good they are. The field changes so quickly that it may be hard for them to keep up.

MIT has a [computational biology course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-91j-foundations-of-computational-and-systems-biology-spring-2014/video-lectures/lecture-1-course-introduction-history-of-computational-biology-overview-of-the-course-course-policies-and-mechanics-dna-sequencing-technologies/) up- I imagine it's probably pretty good.

Abiogenesis is a bit harder, but you might look into the field of exobiology/astrobiology- [here is a list of online courses](https://astrobiology.nasa.gov/education/online-courses/).

Comment: Thanks for replying back with an answer which definitely helps. Can you also point me out some good computational biology courses. Also, books take a lot of time. I may be silly but as a hobby getting a high level knowledge on this will help than to get deeper knowledge.

Comment: updated with computational biology info. Understand about high level knowledge. .

Comment: This should be good for a start. Will come back again if need be. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My standard recommendation for this is [The Cartoon Guide to Genetics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062730991). It may sound overly cute, but it's actually reasonably information dense, and pitched at intelligent readers with no background in biology. I covers the basics of both classical genetics and molecular biology.